# Cannot push to github because non-fast-forward updates were rejected

Tags: git, github

I made a few changes and commits to the wrong branch (really simple changes). So I used git reset --hard "commit" to go back to the correct commit. Now, when I push to github, it says:

```
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
```

how do I push to github? I don't care if I lose the commits that I got rid of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **really** want to override the upstream repository you can use the `-f` flag to force the update

```
git push -f …
```

But, this will bulldoze any upstream changes and replace it with your branch, so don't blame me if you lose history.

Comment: this command shall never be used by someone like him...As far as i can see, he is beginner at git. his team will have some big problems :(

Answer (score 1):

Try pulling first, then commit, and finally push your changes to remote...

Answer (score 0):

try `git fetch remote` and then `git merge remote/master`
if you get some conflict, just resolve it, commit again and push it
this will do the work